# Problems displaying WCS data in QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis-3, wcs

There is done a tsunami risk map by NGI: https://www.ngi.no/eng/Services/Technical-expertise/Tsunamis/Global-Tsunami-risk-modelling-web-service

I try to use the wcs data in QGIS 3.28.0. When I pull in the global data set and set 0 to transparent, I get a map that makes sense:

[image]

If I then start to zoom or pan the map, the wcs data set stays the same:

[image]

I have never seen any other dataset behave like this, but I have not much experience using wcs data. When using the wms data from the same site, everything works fine (although the data are not usable for what I want to do) Have I found a bug in QGIS 3.28, is there something wrong with the setup of the wcs-server, or (most probably) have I done something wrong? The wcs server is serving up data in EPSG:2346, the same crs as my project.

I tried to save the dataset as a geotiff from QGIS; but that also came out completely mangeled. with just some "noise" spread everywhere.

Comment: which format are you retrieving from the WCS

Comment: try with WCS cache setting always network

Comment: I get data as PNG, I also tried the WCS cache setting, but the result was the same.

Comment: in QGIS 3.22 the png from WMS and GeoTIFF from WCS align for me, using always network, however I move the canvas.   for example zoomed in https://gis2.ngi.no/arcgistemp/services/EPOS/TsunamiRunupAndExposure/MapServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-44.870352810900755,10.58750910131061573,9.736555083836083924,57.83750910131061573&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=456&HEIGHT=527&LAYERS=0&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE vs

Comment: https://gis2.ngi.no/arcgistemp/services/EPOS/TsunamiRunupAndExposure/MapServer/WCSServer?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=GeoTIFF&COVERAGE=Runup&BBOX=10.58750910131061573,-44.870352810900755,57.83750910131061573,9.73655508383608392&CRS=EPSG:4326&RESPONSE_CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=456&HEIGHT=527 so maybe you have a bug

Comment: I had to doblecheck, you are right, I get the layer as geoTiff. But, I wonder if I have discovered a bug in QGIS, if I go to the extent setting for the layer, and set it manually, it zooms in correctly

Answer (score 3):

I've got it! When opening the data source, there is an extention checkbox at the bottom, this is by default checked, if it is unchecked, the extention of the WCS layer will adjust as it should.

[image]